# Cannot set isolate: false in feature modules

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I cannot set `isolate: false` in the feature module with `extend: true`.

`App.module.ts`

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: httpTranslateLoader,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  },
  isolate: false
})
```

`FeatureShared.module.ts` (lazy-loaded)

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  },
  isolate: false,
  extend: true
})
```

I have also reset the current language in `TranslateService`

```
export class FeatureSharedModule {
  constructor(protected translateService: TranslateService) {
    const currentLang = translateService.currentLang;
    translateService.currentLang = '';
    translateService.use(currentLang);
  }
}
```

With this setup I can load feature-wise translations files but not main (`app.module`) translations.

Answer (score 1):

The `use` function should be called in both `AppModule` (e.g. within `app.component.ts`) and `FeatureSharedModule`.

**Note:** The default value of `isolate` options is `false`.

Comment: But I just want to inherit parent modules in feature modules

Comment: Could you please create a minimal StackBlitz with the issue?